# Regex for s3 directory path

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use Regex to find an S3 directory path in AWS Data Pipeline.

This is for an S3 Data Node. And then I will do a Redshift Copy from S3 to a Redshift table.

- Example S3 path: S3://foldername/hh=10

Can you we use Regex to find hh=##, where ## could be any number from 0-24.
The goal is to copy all the files in folders where the name is hh=1, hh=2, hh=3, etc.  *(hh is hour)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of regex that will capture the last 1 or 2 digits after 'hh=', at the end of the line.

```
/hh=(\d{1,2})$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex, but unfortunately it didn't work.  I'm sure the regex is fine, but I'm not sure if AWS Data Pipeline can read regex in an S3 directory path. This directory path field is within an S3 Data Node.